# Why is my class abstract? It's override seems to have same signature?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a project which has a class inheritance scheme like this:

```
Drive
    |
    v
FileDrive
    |
    v
StreamDrive
    |
    v
BufferStreamDrive_base
    |
    v
BufferStreamDrive
```

In `Drive` there is a virtual method declared like this:

```
virtual Drive::Type GetDriveType(void) const = 0;
```

Then in `FileDrive` it is overridden with this:

```
virtual Drive::Type GetDriveType(void) const;
```

with the following implementation:

```
Drive::Type
FileDrive::GetDriveType(void) const
{
    return Drive::FILEDRIVE;
}
```

However, when I compile the code I get an error like this:

```
libtool: compile:  x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../../include -I./../../include -I./../../libraries/libmbc -I./../../libraries/libmbutil -I./../../libraries/libmbmath -I./../../libraries/libmbwrap -I./../../libraries/libann -I./../../mbdyn -I./../../mbdyn/base -I./../../mbdyn/struct -I./../../mbdyn/aero -I./../../mbdyn/elec -I./../../mbdyn/thermo -I./../../mbdyn/hydr -I./../../modules -I/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/include/suitesparse -std=c++11 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -pthread -MT constltp_impl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/constltp_impl.Tpo -c constltp_impl.cc  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/constltp_impl.o
In file included from dataman.h:43:0,
                 from bufferstreamdrive.cc:36:
bufferstreamdrive.cc: In function 'Drive* ReadBufferStreamDrive(const DataManager*, MBDynParser&, unsigned int)':
bufferstreamdrive.cc:291:21: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'BufferStreamDrive'
     InputEvery, pSDE));
                     ^
./../../libraries/libmbutil/mynewmem.h:658:14: note: in definition of macro 'SAFENEWWITHCONSTRUCTOR_'
  (pnt) = new constructor
              ^
bufferstreamdrive.cc:287:3: note: in expansion of macro 'SAFENEWWITHCONSTRUCTOR'
   SAFENEWWITHCONSTRUCTOR(pDr, BufferStreamDrive,
   ^
In file included from bufferstreamdrive.cc:39:0:
bufferstreamdrive.h:68:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'BufferStreamDrive':
 class BufferStreamDrive : public BufferStreamDrive_base {
       ^
In file included from tpldrive.h:35:0,
                 from rbk.h:38,
                 from reffrm.h:44,
                 from mbpar.h:110,
                 from dataman.h:47,
                 from bufferstreamdrive.cc:36:
drive.h:117:22: note:   virtual Drive::Type Drive::GetDriveType() const
  virtual Drive::Type GetDriveType(void) const = 0;
                      ^
```

What is the problem here? I can't see it.

**EDIT**

I added the override keyword to the `FileDrive` class method like so:

```
virtual Drive::Type GetDriveType(void) const override;
```

This results in the following error, confirming it does not override anything. I find it odd though that the error refers to `GetDriveTypeA`?

```
libtool: compile:  x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../../include -I./../../include -I./../../libraries/libmbc -I./../../libraries/libmbutil -I./../../libraries/libmbmath -I./../../libraries/libmbwrap -I./../../libraries/libann -I./../../mbdyn -I./../../mbdyn/base -I./../../mbdyn/struct -I./../../mbdyn/aero -I./../../mbdyn/elec -I./../../mbdyn/thermo -I./../../mbdyn/hydr -I./../../modules -I/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/include/suitesparse -std=c++11 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -pthread -MT bicg.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/bicg.Tpo -c bicg.cc  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/bicg.o
In file included from /opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/include/winsock2.h:10:0,
                 from usesock.h:41,
                 from dataman.h:75,
                 from solver.h:59,
                 from bicg.cc:46:
filedrv.h:60:22: error: 'virtual Drive::Type FileDrive::GetDriveTypeA() const' marked 'override', but does not override
  virtual Drive::Type GetDriveType(void) const override;
                  ^
```

I'm cross-compiling this code for windows from Linux (I previously compiled cleanly for native Linux, but without the `-std=c++11` so thought the error might be something to do with this). However, now I have googled and found that there is a windows `GetDriveType` function with an alias `GetDriveTypeA`. Is this possibly some macro madness from Microsoft getting into my code?

Comment: There is a c++11 feature called `override`.  You add it at the end of the function declaration that should be overriding a base class function.  If it doesn't, the compiler will point out the error.

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be really hard to do anything but guess.

Comment: If you mean to `override` a `virtual` function use [the `override` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override). It will make diagnosing the issue much easier.

Comment: are you sure `BufferStreamDrive_base` is derived from `FileDrive`?

Comment: @IosifMurariu, I'm certain `BufferStreamDrive_base` is derived from `FileDrive`: I have `class BufferStreamDrive_base : public StreamDrive`, `class StreamDrive : public FileDrive` and `class FileDrive : public Drive`.

Comment: @UKMonkey, I'll try adding this to see if it can help with diagnosis thanks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, I understand, but at least it's not something totally obvious then.

Comment: I would say, definitely macro madness. I believe somehow there are 2 functions declaration `GetDriveType` and `GetDriveTypeA` and only one of them is defined. Usually the `A` version uses ASCII strings while the other one uses wchar strings. What is the type definition of `Drive::Type` and `Drive::FILEDRIVE`? Are they strings?

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere! `GetDriveType` is a macro to select one of the [Windows functions GetDriveTypeA and GetDriveTypeW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: you might need to `#undef` GetDriveType, esp if you have windows headers included

Comment: `#undef GetDriveType` did the trick, the filed compile. This is irritating though.

Comment: Ahh, the Windows macros. Everybody's favorite C++ problem.

Comment: @BoPersson, for future reference, how did you know from the linked page that this was a macro and not a global function?

Comment: I think I'll make this q a community wiki page.

Comment: @nwp, since your advice lead to the answer, feel free to leave an answer and I'll mark it correct. Otherwise I'll answer myself in a while.

Comment: @crobar I don't know the answer and "use `override`" isn't really an answer. You can answer it if you want. If you manage to make it useful for future visitors you might even get upvotes.

Comment: Only a macro has the effect of randomly renaming things regardless of context. A global function or other construction would be limited by namespace. One nasty approach would be to ensure that all modules have that windows header first, perhaps in a precompiled header, and they will all rename the function and work almost invisibly.

Comment: @crobar - This problem has existed for 20+ years, since someone at Microsoft got the great idea to add 1000s of macros, so you could select the -A or -W versions of API functions taking string parameters. That way they could keep the C interface and not add C++ overloads, or something equally wild and crazy. When I saw the `GetDriveTypeA` in your edit, I immediately recognized this. The *real* function names are also mentioned in the box at the bottom of the linked page.

Comment: @GemTaylor, yes, I meant more _before_ writing the code, if I was looking at the MS docs, how would I know this was a macro.

Comment: To be honest, quite a few times when I get a really weird error message, I just #undef everything in the problem line just incase this is the problem. There are thousands of macros in headers in windows and in unix due to the C legacy.